# Obtaining youtube's page load time via pycurl

Tags: python, http, youtube, pycurl

I was wondering if there is a way to measure the page load time of `youtube.com` or any video hosted on `youtube.com` via `pycurl`.
For example, if I were to measure page load time for `google.com` then I would just perform a query for that url. But for youtube, the first http request doesn't bring back the entire video. Is there a way to do it in pycurl or perhaps via some other method?
I Would be grateful for any pointers regarding this.

Comment: Do you want to measure how long it takes to download the entire video?

Comment: yes ; I want to measure the PLT of a youtube video over pycurl (connected to a tor proxy), similar to the way we can do it for a simple url.

Comment: sort of similar to measuring the time it would take for the video to load on the client's end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Pytube`](https://github.com/nficano/pytube)

Install it with `pip install pytube`

Here is a the code snippet you should be using to download a video.

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y")
video = yt.get('mp4', '720p')
video.download('/tmp/')  # downloaded video to /tmp directory
```

You can time the `video.download` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is an awesome method. However, I want to check youtube latency via tor. Do you think if I do this: 
`socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', SOCKS_PORT)`
`socket.socket = socks.socksocket`

 and then do something like this, it will automatically go through tor?